# How to get HTML element that isn't always visible?

Tags: html, vb.net, drop-down-menu, web

I'm attempting to make a program that will pull information off of a website that my brothers' school uses to display your current grades.

I have basically everything set up, but I'm having trouble with one thing.

I'm using a WebBrowser for this, by the way, I'm aware that I should be using WebRequests.

There is a combobox (dropdown menu) that will be filled with the list of Students that are registered to the parent's account.

However, the students aren't loaded into the combobox until the box is clicked.

I attempted to have the WebBrowser just click the combobox but I couldn't get that to work.

Here is the HTML for the Combobox:

```
<a id="droplist" tabindex="1" href="#students" class="fg-button fg-button-icon-right ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-loading">SELECT A STUDENT<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a>
```

Here is the HTML for the DIV that contains the names while they aren't loaded:

```
<div id="students" class="hidden">
                 <ul></ul>
              </div>
```

Here is the HTML for the DIV that contains the names within the combobox when they're loaded:

```
<div id="students" class="hidden">
                 <ul><li><a href="#" id="17743">Aaron P. Hailey </a></li><li><a href="#" id="16265">Aidan C. Hailey </a></li><li><a href="#" id="19305">Ethan B. Hailey </a></li></ul>
              </div>
```

My guess is that I'll have to send an additional request to get the information or something, but could anyone think of an easy workaround?

I'm a noob to VB so I'm having quite a bit of trouble with this.

Thank you, let me know if you need any additional information!

Comment: You will need to make another request to the server. You need to find the URL for the droplist content. It is in some of the page's javascript somewhere. Please list the definitions for `fg-button fg-button-icon-right ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-loading ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s`.

Comment: Looks like the click event is fired on some other element, not where it should.Can you please make sure of this?

Comment: Look at that <a> tab class: it contains a class called 'ui-state-loading'.  So there must be a css and/or javascript entry somewhere you can investigate.  Look in all <link>'ed files for 'ui-state-loading' and if you are still stuck then post code/urls.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav the browser may be blocking programmatically fired click events

Answer (score 2):

**fireEvent method** - Fires a specified event on the object.

After setting the dropdown value you may try to trigger the event(onchange) attached to dropdown.

```
doc.getElementById("droplist").selectedindex=1
doc.getElementById("droplist").FireEvent("onchange")
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347898/using-vba-excel-to-navigate-a-website-by-changing-dropdown-value/16349937#16349937)

Answer (score 0):

The "combobox" you are looking at has an event listener attached to it. On click this is fired and an ajax request is made to the web server. You should be able to isolate the URI that returns the grade data you require through Chrome Developer Tools under the Network tab. This logs all HTTP requests made by the page. Once you have the URI you should be able to make your own request directly to it and therefore be able to parse the response yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Once the fields have been loaded into the page you can access their value with the standard val function of jquery.

$('#field1').val();