# On a webpage, Change the value of a dropdown box / call a javascript command directly, with an Excel Macro

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I am writing a series of Excel macros to automate interactions with the Agilix Sandbox, http://gls.agilix.com/CallMethod.aspx
I need to change the Method box from GET to POST, here is my code so far:

```
`Const strURL_c As String = "http://gls.agilix.com/CallMethod.aspx"
'Attach domain to the command query
    Dim strUsr_c As String
    Dim i As Integer
'Set up IE variables for use
    Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim ieDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim ddbTypCmd As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Dim tbxUsrFld As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Dim btnSubmit As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Dim tbxDtaFld As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    On Error GoTo Err_Hnd
'Create Internet Explorer Object
    Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
'Navigate to URL
    objIE.Navigate strURL_c
'Wait for page to load
    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
'Get the webpage
    Set ieDoc = objIE.Document
'Get input field and submit button.
    Set tbxUsrFld = ieDoc.all.Item("Post")
    Set btnSubmit = ieDoc.all.Item("Send")
    Set ddbTypCmd = ieDoc.all.Item("Verb")
'Fill Field
    strUsr_c = Range("A1").Value
    doc.getElementById("Verb").value = "POST"
    Call loadXMLDoc("POST", "Dlap.ashx", "text/xml; charset=utf-8", strUsr_c, "*/*")`
```

The final two lines show my two different attempts to create the desired effect.
the last line is my attempt to call the javascript command directly, but it failed.

here is the HTML of the pertinent parts of the webpage:
The javascript I want to call:

`function loadXMLDoc(verb, url, contentType, post, accept) 
{
    xmlhttp=null;

```
// code for Mozilla, etc.
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
}
// code for IE
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
if (xmlhttp!=null)
{
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = onResponse;
    xmlhttp.open(verb,url,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", accept);
    if (verb == "GET")
    {
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
        xmlhttp.send(post);
    }
}
else
{
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.")
}
```

}
`
And the dropdown box I want to change:

`<select name="Verb" id="Verb" size="1">
       <option value="GET" selected="selected">GET</option>
       <option value="POST">POST</option>
  </select>`

Any insight that could be provided would be greatly appreciated

I have already looked at:
[Using excel vba to change the value of a dropdown menu on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003015/using-excel-vba-to-change-the-value-of-a-dropdown-menu-on-a-website)
[Using VBA Excel to navigate a website by changing dropdown value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347898/using-vba-excel-to-navigate-a-website-by-changing-dropdown-value?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an answer that actually worked for changing a drop-down box.

```
Dim methodFld As MSHTML.HTMLSelectElement

Set methodFld = ieDoc.getElementById("Verb")

methodFld.Value = "POST"
```