# How to get website to accept the amount updated on a field

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to submit a form after updated all the fields but the amount field keep changing back to zero no matter what amount updated. Below is the element of that particular field:

```
input id="$PAcqCaseCreation$pTransactionAmount" onchange="onAmountChange(this, 
         document.getElementById('TranNOD').value , 
         document.getElementById('TranDecimalSymbol').value, 
         document.getElementById('TranDecimalSymbolForLocale').value,
         document.getElementById('TranThousandsSep').value , 'false' ); "
class="rightJustifyStyle" type="text" size="10" 
value="" data-changed="false"
```

My code:

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsById( _
        "$PAcqCaseCreation$pTransactionAmount").innerText = fileLink9
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using to solve this in your question.

Comment: Please include it in your question, not in the comments for your question. there is an edit link...

Comment: `getElementsById` should be `getElementById` and set the `Value`, not `innerText`

Comment: changes made accordingly but the value still reset back to zero after proceed button pressed. I believe there is something to do with the data-changed set as false in the element

Comment: Whether you are using some JQuery plugin or custom JQuery script (which will use the data-changed property)? Can you post the related code about that, and the onAmountChange function? It is better to post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, you could also try to set the data-changed attribute to "true", to verify whether the issue is related it. And, you could [debug the VBA script](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) and check the "filelink9" value, make sure it is not 0.

Comment: I can see the amount being updated accordingly on the field but once I submitted it, it will changed back to zero amount. VBA script doesn't prompt with any error.

Comment: I managed to get the amount updated by referring to this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347898/using-vba-excel-to-navigate-a-website-by-changing-dropdown-value

Comment: When submit the data, whether you call some javascript function to handle the data? can you share related code about that? And, you could also try to debug it and check the value. From the link, it seems that they are using dropdownlist, but in your original thread, it seems that you are using input text control. You also using the dropdownlist control? So, I suggest you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then, we could according it to reproduce the problem and solved the problem.